# PHP laravel 5 validation errors with input name as key

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation, laravel-5

I am trying to make an ajax based form for laravel, but im using the laravel validation method to check the input.

The validation errors return a basic list of errors, but I need the specific input name used as a key for each item in the array. I will need this so I can add the message next to the input via javascript.

I have looked at the documentation but cant seem to find anything that will do this. I want to avoid checking each input for errors individually so i can reuse the code on other forms.

Have I missed something here, any ideas on how I can achieve this?

**PHP**

```
$rules = ['username' => 'required', 'password' => 'required'];
$validator = Validator::make(Request::input(), $rules);

if($validator->fails())
{
    $data = $validator->errors()->all();
}
```

**RESULT:**

```
$data = [
    0 => 'The username field is required.',
    1 => 'The password field is required.'
]
```

**DESIRED RESULT:**

```
$data = [
    'username' => 'The username field is required.',
    'password' => 'The password field is required.'
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `$validator->errors()->all()` use `$validator->errors()->messages()` to get the errors keyed by their input names:

```
$data = [
    'username' => [
        0 => "The username field is required."
    ],
    'password' => [
        0 => "The password field is required."
    ],
 ];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you make mistake there.

```
$data = ['validation' => $validator->errors()->all()];
```

Try this

```
$rules = ['username' => 'required', 'password' => 'required'];
$validator = Validator::make(Request::input(), $rules); 
if($validator->fails()) { 
$data = $validator->errors()->all(); 
}
```

Comment: I did thank you, but this doesn't help me solve the issue of the array not containing messages with input names as keys.